# Dynamics CRM with Sharepoint integration issue

Tags: sharepoint, dynamics-crm, sharepoint-online, dynamics-crm-online

We've set up the Sharepoint integration for our Dynamics 365 online instance. It works fine. 
On the document management tab I've chosen 16 entities to have sharepoint integration. The wizard does it's work and it claims that 16 folders have been created. In truth, only 15 have been created. 
When I re-run the wizard, it claims that all 16 folders are existent. It also lists the URLs. 15 work, the 16th shows a 404 HTTP error.

No idea, why the wizard is acting up.

Any idea what I would need to do to manually setup the 16th folder? How's Dynamics linked to Sharepoint? Would it be good enough to create a document collection manually in Sharepoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by access Sharepoint with the Sharepoint Designer. 
I saw that the 16th element was already present but not as a list but as some other type (folder?).

Apparently, the wizard just checks whether an element with that name already exists but it doesn't check the type of the element.

Solution: I deleted the element with that name and ran the wizard again and now it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it didn't do that automatically for you.

When you run the wizard it creates locations in SharePoint, and in CRM; document location records that point to those locations in SharePoint. The link at a folder level is based simply on URL stored as text in CRM document location records.

You should be fine to create the location manually in SharePoint. You could also try deleting the document location records from CRM and running the wizard again. You could also check the document location records have the correct URL configured.

Related reading: [Integrate Microsoft Dynamics 365 with SharePoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334768.aspx).